# invoke command - scriptblock error

Tags: powershell

What used to work in my script doesn't anymore and I am out of ideas.

I'm trying to do the following:

```
Import-Module 'H:\folder\folder1\Remove-Software.psm1'
$sessionoption = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Global:DevicePrimaryIP -Credential $Global:Creds -SessionOption $sessionoption
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock $function:RemoveSoftware
```

This should log into the remote software and remove software, however I keep receiving the following error:

```
Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ScriptBlock'. The
argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running
the command again.
At line:1 char:41
```

Also, I've tried every combination for the scriptblock I can think of.

I've changed things elsewhere in my script but haven't touched this for some time. If anyone else can see the problem anyhelp would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't seem to have a function `RemoveSoftware` in your script.

Comment: The function is imported from another module

Comment: Within that module it contains a function called removesoftware (No hyphen) several processes and directories that are killed/deleted. No arguments are parsed to it either, just to run a small snippet of code on the remote server: 

`function removesoftware{
kill process
delete directory

return "software has been removed"
}`

Comment: What happends if you run `$function:removesoftware` alone? Just to see that the function is defined

Comment: I believe this is where my problem is.. It doesnt actually do anything, also autocomplete doesnt see it.

I must be missing something, it has been imported, I can browse to the directory where this module is located too.

Comment: Are you sure that the other module (the one that contains the RemoveSoftware function) _exports_ that function? If not, the function won't be accessible from outside of the module.

Comment: Kirk is correct. If this is simply a script with some functions and no manifest (which would make it a module) then use dot sourcing instead `. h:\folder\removesoftware.psm1`

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not imported from the module. You can use `-Verbose` to see what's imported. Ex:

```
Import-Module .\Desktop\testmodule.psm1 -Verbose
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Users\frode\Desktop\testmodule.psm1'.
VERBOSE: Exporting function 'testModuleFunction'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'testModuleFunction'.
```

If the "module" is just a script-file with a few functions you could try to simply dot-source them in:

```
. 'H:\folder\folder1\Remove-Software.psm1'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, So I dot sourced it and it exports and imports "removesoftware". And I am able to run the command locally, however once I put it into the -scriptblock within the invokecommand I am presented with the error where my scriptblock argument is null.

I work for a large IT company and our infrastructure is complicated, but I dont think it should be interfering with this? I am able to create sessions and map psdrives with the target server.

Infact, a month ago I had this working.. Do you have any other ideas?

Thanks for the help so far

Comment: Right! So I am able to put the `removesoftware` function in a varaible called `$test1` and I am able to use it with the `invoke-command` cmdlet and was successful. 

-verbose showed previously that the function was being imported, however when the function is in another module, it seems it cannot run remotely.

I would really prefer all my functions to be in their own modules as this script is really long.. Does anyone else have anymore ideas?